# Python selenium find element by xpath or css selector

Tags: javascript, python, css, selenium, automation

how can i click on the "NATIONAL" text with python selenium

```
<div class="ellipsis__content">
    <ul class="breadcrumb_new" id="breadcrumb">
       <li>
         <span>NATIONAL</span>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried these below things,

```
find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='breadcrumb']/li/span")
find_element_by_css_selector("#breadcrumb > li > span")
```

Both the methods not working, any idea here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, should work for you:

```
ele=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='breadcrumb']//span")
ele.click()
```

Comment: Found the initial element using //*[@id='breadcrumb'] which means I will search the entire HTML source for an element having this ID; predominantly done by //*, which in this case also indicates that my target is under this umbrella and then directly target the span tag using //span.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to wait till element is rendered properly.

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='breadcrumb']/li/span").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='breadcrumb']/li/span"))).click()
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Answer (score 0):

Already this question has an answered but adding couple of points.

> I tried these below things,
>
> ```
> find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='breadcrumb']/li/span")
> ```

The `id` `breadcrumb` is part of `ul` tag but you are referring `div` tag. It should work if try as below.

```
find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@id='breadcrumb']/li/span")
```

> find_element_by_css_selector("#breadcrumb > li > span")

There is nothing wrong with `CSS` locator. It should work still if you are seeing issue you may need to debug and see or try by adding some `explicit` value.

[image]